# How to say "What the world needs now is Love, sweet love"?

Tags: translation

I am having trouble translating this line "What the world needs now is love, sweet love"

Here's my attempt:

> Kio la mondo bezonas nun estas amo, dolĉa amo

I would appreciate an explanation for any corrections.

Dankon :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your translation sounds nice, but you need to put the accusative marker on *kio*:

> Kio**n** la mondo bezonas nun, estas amo, dolĉa amo

Some people may argue that you also need to add *tio*. The *kion* introduces a subphrase which references something in the main phrase. Usually when the two things have a different role in the main phrase and the subphrase (in this case, one is the subject and the other is the object), you need to add the *tio* that is being referenced to make this clear. Then it would be like this:

> **Tio**, kio**n** la mondo bezonas nun, estas amo, dolĉa amo

However I think this isn’t really necessary and it’s a bit pedantic. [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/ti-forlaso.html#i-pho) has some similar examples where the *tio* is left out.

So I would recommend the version without *tio* because it sounds less heavy.

Comment: I know comma rules aren't as well-defined in Esperanto as in some other languages, but I strongly feel like the subclause "kion la mondo bezonas nun" should be wrapped with commas: "Kion la mondo bezonas nun, estas amo, dolĉa amo." or "Tio, kion la mondo bezonas nun, estas amo, dolĉa amo."

Comment: @das-g Yes, I agree. I’ve edited the response. Thanks